# How to change one character in a .stringz (LC3)

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm looking for a way to change singular characters inside a stringz in the LC3.

For example if we have:

```
SUBR
    LEA R0, STR ;Loading string into R0
    ADD R6, R0, A_31 ;Seeing if its above/below '1'
    BRn ND
    ADD R6, R0, A_39 ;Seeing if its above/below '9'
    BRP ND

    ;
    ;Some code that would change the current 'num' to ascii 0
    ;
    
ND  RET

A_31 .fill -31 ;Ascii -'1'
A_39 .fill -39 ;Ascii -'9'
.blkw 100
STR .stringz "aBcDeFg12345abC?-"
    .end
```

Now, this is somewhat pseudocode because I'm not sure how to actually do what I want(I understand I can't just LEA the string and then do the ADD to check). In this example, I'd like to be able to read each character in the string, and change it to a zero if it isn't already the ASCII value for a number 1-9.

I have some ideas that it needs to use LDR and STR somehow to increment through the memory addresses while changing the chars in-place (i.e. not swapping back and forth between two registers while checking each char), but I'm really not sure how to do it practically.

Any help is greatly appreciated <3

Answer (score 0):

You want an algorithm that uses a pointer to search the array elements for certain qualities.

That's usually done with a loop that extracts one element at a time, checks the qualities of that element, and then moves on to the next.

The LEA you have is used for initializing a CPU register as pointer to refer to a label.

That pointer is just a number, but once you've have it, you can (1) dereference it to get an element, (2) increment it to refer to the next byte of the string.

LDR and STR accomplish dereferencing.  Since a pointer is just a number, regular addition can advance it.

Let's look at a sample loop that computes max:

```
        LEA R0, ARRAY      // pointer variable
        AND R1, R1, #0     // current max, clear to zero (good for numbers >= 0)

LOOP,   LDR R2, R0, #0     // fetch element from array
        NOT R3, R2         // negate via two's complement (part 1)
        ADD R3, R3, #1     // negate via two's complement (part 2)
        ADD R3, R1, R3     // compare the current max with element
        BRp SKIP           // is current max larger than the array element?
        ADD R1, R2, #0     // yes: capture new max (no: skip this)
SKIP,   ADD R0, R0, #1     // either way: continue on and increment pointer
        BR LOOP
```

Not shown is how to exit such loop (when the end of the array is reached and thus all element have been processed) since that was not part of your question.